# jQuery select option deselect

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-select

I am trying to deselect a select option element with jQuery. Here is my scenario:

I have 3 select options:
[ Select 1 ]
[ Select 2 ]
[ Select 3 ]

**Scenario:** Select 1 is prefilled with data from an ajax call. So Select 1 has opt 1, opt 2, opt 3, etc.
When you select an option from Select 1, it fills Select 2 with data, and when you select from Select 2 it fills Select 3, and so on.

Depending on what you select, it puts the values from those ":selected" options and apply to a variable called "url".

So in the case that you only select "Select 1":
url = 'search/for/this/select1/'

In th case that you select "Select 1" and "Select 2"
url = 'search/for/this/select1/select2/

And so on.

This is the way im writing the jQuery code:

```
var url = 'search/for/this';  
if(element1.is(':selected')) {
  url += element1.val();    
  // makes url = 'search/for/this/select1val/';  
     if(element2.is(':selected')) {  
        url += element1.val();    
         // makes url = 'search/for/this/select1val/select2val/';  
        if(element3.is(':selected')) {  
            url += element1.val();    
            // makes url = 'search/for/this/selectval1/select2val/select3val/';  

         }  
    }  
}
```

The problem is, this requires that I de-select the next options after the previous one was selected, but since there is data that is filled in, it seems to automatically return true when it passes through the ":selected" condition check in the code example above. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this functionality? If I am not making my issue clear. Please requested more details and I will add them in. Thanks
-Chris-

Comment: Is it a typo that each time url get's element1's .val()?

Comment: when these lines of code executes? I suggest you should call a method on onchange event of the select box and then do some if else logic.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're adding a lot of complexity to what should otherwise be a reasonably simple task.

As you've described it, you want to get the values of all selected values from your drop-down lists and concatenate them into a URL.

The jQuery `$.map()` function is an excellent fit for this example.  Try the following code:

```
var searchTerms = $('option:selected').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join('/');

url = 'search/for/this/' + searchTerms;
```

You would then execute this code when you needed to actually get the selected values (e.g. when your search is submitted, for example.  You may also want to get the option's text rather than its actual value, in which case the code would change to `return $(this).text();`

Comment: Worked just fine. I knew I was over complicating it. I haven't used the map() function before, but I can see that I will be using it alot in the future. Thanks alot Phil.